# How can I align two nodes to the left in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

I have two unaligned nodes

```
|AAAAAAA|

        |B|
```

and I want to have the node with the B aligned to the left of the node with AAAs and below it

```
|AAAAAAA|

|B|
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). Otherwise please state what is missing so that people can help you better.

Answer (score 49):

You can position "B" below and left of "AAA" without having to know the position of it using the `positioning` library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] (A) at (4,5) {AAAA};
    \node [draw,below=of A.west,anchor=west] (B) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image: Result]

Comment: Note that you can change the distance by adding a value before `of`, e.g. `below=2cm of A`.

Comment: Thanks, your examples helped me to understand the workings of anchor: it makes a node's anchor point (north, east, ...) coincide with the node's position  point (defined with "at (x,y)", "below=of p", etc).

Comment: For example, using

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
\node[draw, anchor=west] (1) {AAAAAAAA};
\node[draw, below=of 1.south west, anchor=north west] (2) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

we can left align the two nodes and have a precise distance of 5mm between them. Thanks a lot. @MichaelUmmels

Comment: Important note: one must use `below=of A.west, anchor=west` (which is what Martin has written) not `anchor=west, below=of A.west` (which looks just as good, but seems not to work).

Comment: @MartinScharrer Why does placing `anchor=west` after `below` instruction works, but not the other way around? (Just like John pointed out in the comment above)

Comment: @drozzy: `below` seems to modify/overwrite the anchor position.

Answer (score 23):

Use `anchor=west` for both nodes. For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=west] (1) at (0,1) {AAAAAAAA};
\node[anchor=west] (2) at (0,0) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now: you are placing the west anchors of two nodes at two vertically aligned points. That does the trick, the only limitation is that if the top node increases its heigth you have to move the point of the second node further below. To avoid this the second node could be placed using "below=of 1.south west".

Comment: Yes, I agree that Martin's solution (inlcuding `node distance`) is more flexible.