# How can I align text across two nodes in a Tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=left,font={\small\bfseries}] at (-30 pt, 30pt) {99.99\%        $500 \mu s$};
\node[align=left,font={\small\bfseries}] at (-30 pt, 10pt) {Median Latency $5 \mu s$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I make the `500 us` align with the `5 us` in the rendered image?

More specifically, I want it to align almost exactly like I have it in the plain text in the code above, with the left edge of `99` aligning with the left edge of `Median`, as well as having the numbers line up.

I tried using `&` as I would when trying to align two equations, but it just causes an error.

Comment: What about using `tabular`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First solution

Using your code sample, you can use `right` or `anchor=west` to [align both nodes to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13671/how-can-i-align-two-nodes-to-the-left-in-tikz) together with a `makebox` to make sure ensure the left part of the text takes the same space in both nodes and are vertically aligned (see @egreg comment below):

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[font={\small\bfseries},left] at (-30 pt, 30pt) {\parbox{3cm}{99.99\%}$500 \mu s$};
  \node[font={\small\bfseries},left] at (-30 pt, 10pt) {\parbox{3cm}{Median Latency}$5 \mu s$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

### Second solution

Or you could use another node for the right part of the text (but both texts are not vertically aligned):

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-30 pt, 30pt) node[font={\small\bfseries},left] {99.99\%} ++(3,0) node[left] {$500 \mu s$};
  \draw (-30 pt, 10pt) node[font={\small\bfseries},left] {Median Latency} ++(3,0) node[left] {$5 \mu s$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Second solution output]

Comment: The horizontal alignment is good, the vertical is bad.

Comment: Indeed! Then I guess, I could specify the height of the `parbox` but It wouldn't be very clean.

Comment: Use `\makebox[3cm][l]{99.9\%}`, not `\parbox`

Answer (score 5):

If you need to place them in two *separate* nodes I would recommend using a `\makebox`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I would also highly recommend you use [the `siunitx` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) for units to ensure that they are correctly and consistently formatted as I did in this example.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*{\Widest}{\small\bfseries Median Latency}
\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{\Widest}][l]{#1} #2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[font={\small\bfseries},anchor=west] at (-30 pt, 30pt) {\MakeBox{99.99\%}{$\SI{500}{\micro \second}$}};
  \node[font={\small\bfseries},anchor=west] at (-30 pt, 10pt) {\MakeBox{Median Latency}{$\SI{5}{\micro \second}$}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `matrix of nodes`, or use a multipart node, or -- depending on what you really want to do -- just place a `tabular` in a `node`. (Of course, as egreg hints at with his comment, if this isn't part of a larger `tikzpicture` just use a `tabular` and drop the `tikzpicture` altogether.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\section*{With matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={font={\small\bfseries},text width=3cm,align=left},
column 2/.style={text width=1cm,align=left}] {
99.99\% & $500\mu s$ \\
Median Latency & $5\mu s$ \\
};

% to demonstrate that individual cells can be referenced
\draw [red,latex-] (m-1-2) -- ++(0,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Tabular in node}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node {%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\small\bfseries 99.99\% & $500\mu s$ \\
\small\bfseries Median Latency & $5\mu s$
\end{tabular}
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Multipart node}

\begin{tikzpicture}[splitnode/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split parts=2,rectangle split part align={left},text width=3cm,font={\small\bfseries}}]

\node[splitnode] at (-30 pt, 30pt) {99.99\%   \nodepart{two}$500 \mu s$};
\node[splitnode] at (-30 pt, 10pt) {Median Latency \nodepart{two}$5 \mu s$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an old way of doing it in the sense that I haven't seen the command `\shortstack` around  for many years. You can change the separation of both lines modifying the dimension in `\vspace` and if you don't like the `500` entering above the `Latency` you can add some `\hspace` before the `$5\mu s`. However, I should not align the `5 hundred` with the `5 (unit)`, but the units with the units.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz \node[font={\small\bfseries}] {\shortstack{%
                       99.99\%\hfill $500 \mu s$\\ 
                       \vspace{1ex}             \\
                       Median Latency $5 \mu s$}};

\end{document}
```

As @egreg has suggested, `tabular` is probably the best way of doing it but if you want less separation between both lines, you must add negative `\vspace`in the middle row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz \node[font={\small\bfseries}] {%
        \begin{tabular}{ll}%{l@{}r}
          99.99\%        & $500 \mu s$ \\
          \vspace{0pt}   &             \\
          Median Latency & $5   \mu s$
        \end{tabular}};

\end{document}
```