# tikz rectangle nodes fail to align

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, alignment, tikz-node, anchor

I'm trying to align 2 nodes (instr0 and instr1) to the left. I've followed [How can I align two nodes to the left in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13671/how-can-i-align-two-nodes-to-the-left-in-tikz) however it doesn't quite work as I'm getting the following error:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named instr0.west is known.
```

Here is a minimal reproducible example.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, decorations.pathreplacing, positioning}

\tikzstyle{instruction-bits-variable} = [rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    draw,
    text centered,
    minimum height=1em]

\begin{document}

\begin {figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

    \node [instruction-bits-variable,
           rectangle split parts=7,
           label={west:{instr 0:}}] (instr0) {};

    \node [instruction-bits-variable,
           rectangle split parts=8,
           node distance = 2em,
           label={west:{instr 1:}},
           below of = instr0.west,
           anchor=west] (instr1) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption {Fixed length instructions}
\label {fig:instruction-format-components}
\end {figure}

\end{document}
```

It works if I remove the `.west` bit but the nodes are no longer aligned. I'm not sure why the `.west` attribute is not recognised.

**Can anyone see what the issue is?**

Comment: write `below = of instr0.west,`

Comment: @AndréC I've tried that. It would cause the top node to be centred and the bottom node to move all the way to the left.

Comment: Not when I compile with pdflatex. Give your complete and compileable code. With which engine do you compile your code?

Comment: @AndréC I've updated the example

Comment: @AndréC You're correct. That seems to have solved it. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, please use `\tikzset{instruction-bits-variable/.style={rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    draw,
    text centered,
    minimum height=1em}}` instead.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Good point. I'll start using that.

Comment: BTW, you didn't make a "syntax error", you were just using the syntax that does not use the `positioning` library, which is also deprecated, one reason being that it does not support the positioning relative to anchors. But by itself the syntax is not an error, just deprecated and does not support the same features as the `positioning` syntax does.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat So `below of = instr0` is deprecated and one should use `below = of instr0` when using the `positioning` library.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You did not make an error, but were using a deprecated tool for a  task it cannot deal with.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat As comments are transitive, could you suggest an edit to the answer to include the points you mentioned?

Comment: @John I'd prefer if someone else does that. Perhaps it is simplest if we keep things as they are. I do not want to start an edit war.

Comment: @John `below of = instr0` is not depreciated and works. But not `below of = instr0.west` which requires the use of the `positioning` library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You made a syntax error when using the positioning library. It is necessary to write `below = of...`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, decorations.pathreplacing, positioning}

\tikzstyle{instruction-bits-variable} = [rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    draw,
    text centered,
    minimum height=1em]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

    \node [instruction-bits-variable,
           rectangle split parts=7,
           label={west:{instr 0:}}] (instr0) {};

    \node [instruction-bits-variable,
           rectangle split parts=8,
           node distance = 2em,
           label={west:{instr 1:}},
           below  =of instr0.west,
           anchor=west] (instr1) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption {Fixed length instructions}
\label {fig:instruction-format-components}
\end {figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly shorter code, recent syntax for determining of node style:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, 
                decorations.pathreplacing, positioning,
                shapes,}

\tikzset{instruction-bits-variable/.style = {% <---
            rectangle split, 
            rectangle split horizontal,
            rectangle split parts=#1,        % <---
            draw, align=center, minimum height=1em}
        } 

\begin{document}
    \begin {figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm and 4mm % <--- 
                        ]
\node [instruction-bits-variable=7,
       label=west:{instr 0:}] (instr0) {};
\node [instruction-bits-variable=8,
       label=west:{instr 1:},
       below = of instr0.west, anchor=west] (instr1) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption {Fixed length instructions}
\label {fig:instruction-format-components}
    \end {figure}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as it is in other answer.